# How to get a few MAX and MIN values from a SQL Server table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get a few scalar values from a single table.

This is my query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(column1) AS bmax," +
                         "MIN(column1) AS bmin," +
                         "MAX(column2) AS amax, " +
                         "MIN(column2) AS amin," +
                         "MAX(column3) AS cmax," +
                         "MIN(column3) AS cmin " +
                  "FROM MainTable WHERE AND year > " + (DateTime.Today.Year - 1);
```

How can I read the values from it? I've already tried the following and looking in the `SqlDataReader` doc on msdn:

```
int.Parse(dr["bmax"].ToString());
int.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
int.Parse(dr[0][0].ToString());
int.Parse(dr.GetSqlValue(0).ToString());
```

I know the query works because when I get an exception to one of my trials I can hover over the `SqlDataReader` object and go to results view >>> `[0]{system.data.common.datarecordinternal}` >>> non-public members >>> `_values{object[6]}` I can see 6 rows with the values I tried to get.

I'm aware that I can get each value separately using 6 different queries and to `ExecuteScalar` but I'd like to use the same query if possible

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?is it a null reference exception?

Comment: post the full C# block. There's no Read() statement here. If that is you're full code then you have to dr.Read() first. Not sure why you would see 6 rows, the return should only be one row since it seems to all be aggregate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
int bmax, bmin;
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
      if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
         bmax = reader.GetInt32(0);
      if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
         bmin = reader.GetInt32(1);
      // and so on
    }
}
```

Please note this will get you result for the first row from your query results.

If it should be several rows in the resultset, consider using `while (reader.Read())` loop.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question right something like this should help:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    string str0 = reader[0].ToString();
                    string str1 = reader[1].ToString();
                    string str2 = reader[2].ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I wouldn't use reader[0], use the name of the column, that way if the query ever changes orders for whatever reason it doesn't kill you. Also, the return values are numeric, not sure why you would use strings.

Comment: agreed, but i don't know the names of the columns :) , that said i should have written something about that. good advice!